# simple One to many relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

i have a user(ADMIN) and a student i want them to be in one table that is on the dashboard controller i cant find and exact answer in the searching please help me

**Student model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User", 'User_id', 'id');
}
```

**User model**

```
public function student()
{
    return $this->hasMany("App\Student");
}
```

**DashboardController**

```
$users = User::with('user_id');

return view('superadminpage.admin_table')->with('users', $users);
```

Comment: change your `student()` method to `students()`, and use `User::with('students')`

Comment: still cant view the student

Answer (score 0):

first change the User_id to user_id at student model

```html
 public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo("App\User", 'user_id');
        }
```

second change at DashboardController

```
 $users = User::with('user_id'); to $users = User::with('student')->all();
```

first change the User_id to user_id at student model

```html
 public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo("App\User", 'user_id' , 'id');
        }
```

second change at DashboardController

```
 $users = User::with('user_id'); to $users = User::with('student')->all();
```

it's also good to change at user model `public function student()` to `public function students()` and call at DashboardController `$users = User::with('students')->all();`

Comment: hi bro still cant view the student in my view can you help me.

Comment: used $users = User::query()->with("students")->all();

Answer (score 0):

Edit Student model code like this:

```
public function user(){
     return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
}
```

Also edit User model:

```
   public function students(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Student");
   }
```

then use in DashboardController

```
 $users = User::query()->with("students")->all();

 return view('superadminpage.admin_table')->with('users', $users );
```

then you can do this:

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $students = $user->students;

    // use
}
```

Comment: `foreach($users as $user){
    $students = $user->students;

    // use
}` where should i put this ?

Answer (score 0):

> public function users()
>       {
>
> ```
>     return $this->hasMany('App\User');
>
> }
> ```
>
> public function role()
>
> ```
> {
>   return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
> }
> ```